# Truffle console: assert.equal, how to use exception for testing purposes?

Tags: truffle-console, assert

I want to check the value returned by getName() function:

```
pragma solidity >= 0.5.0 < 0.7.0;
 
contract SimpleContract {
  string  public name;
  constructor() public {
     name = 'abs';  
  }
  function getName() public view returns(string memory) {
      return (name);
   }
}
```

I am using using assert.equal(....) in truffle console but it is not printing the message:

> > truffle(development)> sci = await
> > SimpleContract.at('0xDa0463c841E7D822f6281240cD7593bA3FD4BB0f');
> > truffle(development)> await sci.getName();
> > 'abs'
> > truffle(development)> value = await sci.getName();
> > undefined

> truffle(development)> assert.equal(value, 'abs', "Both are equal");

> undefined

> > truffle(development)>

How can I print the message "Both are equal". On the other hand, assert.equal(...)generates exception when the vales are not equal.How can I use assert.equal(...) in this case, to indicate that values are equal.

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert.equal` will throw an exception when the values are *not* equal.

```js
assert.equal("foo", "bar", "Must be equal"); // AssertionError: Must be equal
```

If it does not throw anything, it means that your the variables are equal.

Also note that you don't need a getter for public variables in Solidity. It will automatically create a getter function for public variables.